# EC2 implementation of ECS doesnt stop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am currently having a docker container running on a fargate that is working well automatically turning on and off to run a workload. Due to restrictions in memory and I want to have more GBs than 30GB, I wanted to move to EC2 version of ECS task. The task is running in EC2 instance created but doesnt turn off after the task is completed.

I want to know how to configure this automatically using ECS.

Comment: What is your current exact setup?

Answer (score 0):

[ECS Cluster Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-auto-scaling.html) should be able to scale your EC2 cluster back to 0 instances if you have no tasks running on it. Have a look at [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deep-dive-on-amazon-ecs-cluster-auto-scaling/).

Comment: Its not doing that, thats my concern